# Create RPM through MakeFile and Tar ball

Tags: git, makefile, tar, rpm

I am trying to generate RPM using MakeFile, but it fails to work.
Here I show an example

System is CentOs 7

1- I have my application here

```
/applicationGroup/group01/app01
```

2- Here is what I have for sake of example

```
/applicationGroup/group01/app01/public
/applicatoinGroup/group01/app01/lib
/applicationGroup/group01/app01/.git
/applicationGroup/group01/app01/somephp.php
/applicationGroup/group01/app01/MakeFile
/applicationGroup/group01/app01/rpm.spec
/applicationGroup/group01/app01/build
```

3- Here is what I want to do

1. 1- setup the MakeFile, so it create the tarball and save it to
   build/SOURCE

   2- the tar ball should exclude : MakeFile, rpm.spec, .git and
   .gitignore

   3- then MakeFile use the rpmbuild to create the rpm

   4- then run: make rpm clean

   5- the generated rpm should be relocatable. That means, i use the
   prefix=/mynewlocation/myappV02, and install it in a new location on
   same machine.

I need the simplest MakeFile and rpm.spec example to achieve above example.
My problem is, when I run the generated rpm, it install it in its original folder location. even though I use the prefix= option.

```
Name: myAppName 

Version: 1.0.1
Release: 1
Summary: myApp description
License: free
URL: http://myapp.somedomain.com
BuildArch: noarch
Source0: MyappName_V1.0.1.tar.gz
Prefix: /app01
%description
My software Description

%define_missing_doc_files_terminate_build 0

%prep
%autosetup -c package

%build


%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}
cp -rp * %{buildroot}

%files
/app01/*
```

%changelog

Comment: Have you tried to read any manual about relocatable rpms? I googled this: http://rpm5.org/docs/api/relocatable.html Additionally: I understand you already have some spec file. Can you share it here? By the way: why you want to use makefile?

Comment: I need to use MakeFile to automate the deployment process. as one single step for developers to create the rpm and one step for DevOp to install the rpm. There is more into this, this is just part of the solution. Docker and git CI/DI is part of it. By the way, i don't have the spec file handy now.

Comment: ok, i found the spec, included above

Comment: You can't do anything with Make until you know how to do i *without* Make. You must figure out how to build a satisfactory rpm on the command line, before you worry about writing a Makefile.